# Convert numeric value field in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have an `Accno` field containing the following Numeric Value:

```
1,147,852,963,369,258.00
```

But I would like to convert it to:

```
114785296369258
```

How can I do that via Formula Fields in Crystal Reports 2008?

Comment: please indicate what did you try so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the crystal report designer view:

Right mouse click on that field, and select "Format object". Select "Custom Style" in the Style list, and click "Customize". Untick "Thousands Separator", and any other unwanted formatting.

Failing that, you could try selecting the field and deleting the "," value from the property "ThousandSeperator" in your properties window.

Hope this helps!